# Does this environment need any changes (SCOBY)

Tags: yeast, bacteria

Trying to grow a SCOBY following the video linked below.

It’s currently day 4.5 and I maybe see something very faint but not even sure about that.

I have it in a bedroom around 70, window closed, on a shelf with a blanket over it.

Does it look like it needs any changes in the jar or in the environment?

https://youtu.be/LVwCIMHnbSk

[image]

[image]

[![enter image description here][3]][3]
[image: ent here]

Answer (score 0):

This all looks good, just a couple notes:

- you may want to try increasing the temperature a bit
- try adding the sugar while the liquid is still hot, rather than cooling it before adding sugar

I've done this before in a similar fashion. I followed this article about [how to harvest a scoby from store bought kombucha](https://blog.kegoutlet.com/harvesting-a-kombucha-scoby-from-a-bottle-of-gts-kombucha/).